# Insert data from tableA to tableB

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

So I want to insert data from tableA to tableB depending on their pvkey. Each row has his pvkey and one row under the same pvkey can have several records and each of these records has his unique cnkey. Cnkey is unique for any data in table. When I am inserting data from tableA there is no column Cnkey and in tableB there is Cnkey.

```
INSERT INTO CONTHIST (CONTTYPE, ASSIGNEDTO, CONTDATE, SOURCE, CNKEY) 
    SELECT ContactType, ASSIGNEDTO, DATE, SourceCode, ?!?!  
    FROM MopUpEOC
    WHERE Pvkey in (1,5,7,9,11,20)
```

Can you help me with this, thank you :D

Comment: So what do you want to insert into the Cnkey column?

Comment: not sure what the problem is. If the column doesnt exist then just dont include it in the insert statement - take `CNKEY` out of the `INSERT INTO` LINE (Assuming it has a default value)

Comment: It says: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CNKEY', table 'Progress.dbo.CONTHIST'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
This happens when I don't include column Cnkey.
I tried to insert 0 but it has to be some kind of record because every time when new record is inserted he needs to have Cnkey that is unique for every record.

Comment: Maybe you should just start by doing a SELECT * INTO newTable FROM MopUpEOC WHERE etc... for only the columns you want.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that could help you:

- Check if `CnKey` is the serial primary key of your table. If it is the serial primary key, you have no problem.
- Check if `CnKey` is `NOT NULL`, if not, you can change it's value later, or you can set a default value.

For example, the column `CnKey` is `NOT NULL`, then you can use following Query to allow `NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE TableB ALTER COLUMN CnKey INT NULL
```

Change `INT` to the real type of your column.

Or you set a Default Value:

```
ALTER TABLE TableB ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName DEFAULT 'DefaultName' FOR CnKey;
```

Comment: Cnkey data and system type is float and primary key is true.